# React check if property exists AND is false

Tags: reactjs, boolean

I have some form inputs and I'd like to be able to set some to be required and some to be optional. I'd like to use the `required` property so that the HTML is semantically correct:

```
<input onBlur={this.handleBlur} name="first_field" />
<input onBlur={this.handleBlur} name="first_field" required={false} />
<input onBlur={this.handleBlur} name="first_field" />
```

I'd prefer to add `required={false}` so I don't have to add the required prop to every field. However, checking for this then becomes somewhat strange:

```
handleBlur = (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === '') {
    // show an error if field empty and required
    // NOT explicitly set to false
    if (!this.props.required) {
      setError('This field is required') 
    }
  }
}
```

I can't do `if (!this.props.required)` because that would be true if the property isn't declared.

Is there a simpler way to handle this than the double check?

**UPDATE:** I hastily assumed this was a code issue, but after some discussion in comments below I now believe it is a semantic issue of how the HTML 'required' attribute should be used, OR how to handle this with React. I chose not to delete the question since there may be some value to this for others in future.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. In particular, you should show a simple component which illustrates the concept you are asking about.

Comment: Apologies, I've fleshed out the example a little.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. How is the `handleBlur` function related to the `input` elements above it?

Comment: I omitted the event handler to keep the inputs concise. I've added them back in.

Comment: See my edited answer. In short, your prop should be named `optional` instead of `required`.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are trying to avoid setting `required` on each of the child `input` elements when they are in fact required. As I state in my answer, you shouldn't try to do this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I believe you are right, and I believe this is the root problem, not the original code question - I'm not sure how to handle answering/commenting in a way that works well for stack overflow. Thoughts?

Comment: You've received several answers along with edits as your question has been more clear. Up-vote the ones you find helpful and accept one if it actually solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that the fundamental question you are asking is how to modify the meaning of the `required` attribute on an `input` element. The answer is: **You cannot do so.** Instead, you should write your own `OptionalInput` component that has a prop named `optional` and renders `<input required={!optional}>` Then you can use this component wherever you wish in the way you are asking about here.

Comment: Yeah I think you shouldn't put custom props on DOM elements: https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to change the semantics of `required`. This attribute should default to `false` if it is not present. Explicitly setting `required={false}` is perfectly fine. However, changing the meaning when `required` is not present seems like a bad practice to me.

Instead, you can write your own component. You can name it `OptionalInput` for example. Give it a prop named `optional` and then have a `render()` function with something like this:

```
render() {
    return <input name={this.props.name}
                  id={this.props.id}
                  ...
                  required={!this.props.optional}/>
}
```

You will also need to add props for all `input` attributes which you want to support.

Comment: This might be true - I considered switching for `optional={true}` instead, but now I'm adding a new prop to the HTML input instead of using the existing attribute. I could set required to true in all cases except when explicitly set to false..

Comment: @Toby You can easily add an `optional` prop to your own component. Then you will have to add `required={!optional}` to all of the children `input` elements.

Comment: shouldn't it be `!this.props.optional` in your snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify it using `defaultProps`:

```
defaultProps: {
   required: true
}
```

If the property is not defined, `true` will be used instead.

However, it might be better to invert the condition and call it `optional`, then you will be able to use it simply as:

```
 <input name="first_field" optional />
```

Comment: I did consider this - but it seems semantically incorrect to add an attribute rather than use the existing HTML attribute. I hadn't thought of using propTypes for this though, I'm looking into that now.

Comment: @Toby React is not HTML. Having `required={true}` by default is a bit unexpected for users of your component exactly because it behaves differently than in HTML.

Comment: Adding `optional` to an input element won't do anything since `input` does not recognize this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to approach this would be with a forced boolean casting. Any falsey values like undefined, null, 0, or false will result in false, any other value will be considered true. In this case, since required doesn't exist until it's specified as a prop, it will return false until assigned its value. You can try the following on your browser's terminal;

```
const data = {};
console.log('no required has been defined, ', !!data.required);
data.required = false;
console.log('required has been set to false, ', !!data.required);
data.required = true;
console.log('required should be true now, ', !!data.required);
delete data.required;
console.log('back to not defined, ' !!data.required);
```

Hope that helps!